# How do I get a vector to take in 2 different classes with the same base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I know in C# there is a way to make a variable take in values so long as they share a base class, but I'm stumped with C++. Is what I am trying to do possible?

This is what my code looks like:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        virtual void Setup() = 0;       
        virtual void DisplayText() = 0;
};

class A: public BaseClass
{
    public:     
        void Setup();       
        void DisplayText();
};

class B: public BaseClass
{
    public:     
        void Setup();       
        void DisplayText();
};


//main.cpp

A a;
B b;

std::vector<BaseClass> vector = std::vector();

void main()
{
    vector.push_back(a);
    vector.push_back(b);

    for_each (vector.begin(), vector.end(), vector.Setup());

    return 0;
}
```

With what I have right now though it is giving me this error when I try running this:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function
"std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=BaseClass,,Alloc=std::allocator<BaseClass>]"
matches the argument list
argument types are: (A*)
object type is: std::vector<BaseClass, std::allocator<BaseClass>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but try creating smart pointers instead of raw objects, and push those into the vector.

Comment: In C++, void main() is not standard, it should be corrected to int main().

Comment: @adam10603 what's a smart pointer?

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here. First:

```
std::vector<BaseClass> vector = std::vector();
```

That's invalid syntax, `vector` is not a type so you can't create one like you do on the right hand side. Just this is sufficient:

```
std::vector<BaseClass> vector;
```

Second, this is not how you call `for_each`:

```
for_each (vector.begin(), vector.end(), vector.Setup());
```

There is no `Setup()` function on `vector`. And if there was, that's not even the `Setup` you wanted to call. What you want to use is [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

```
for_each (vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::Setup));
```

Once we get there, then we get to the major problem in your code: you're [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) all of your objects! Well, first, we're trying to store abstract classes in a `vector` by value, which is not possible. And if it was, it wouldn't do what you wanted anyway because of the slicing issue. What you need to do is change your `vector` to store pointers to `BaseClass` instead:

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> vector;
vector.push_back(&a);
vector.push_back(&b);
```

And then, and only then, will your code compile. Well, assuming you provide definitions for your virtual overrides somewhere - otherwise it won't link.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a reference for the typename given to the vector?

Comment: @Mark You mean `vector<BaseClass&>`? No. The element type must be assignable.

Comment: @Barry I have most of what you wrote implemented now. I need to make a change though. I want to have the vector in my base class as a static value and i need to call it in my main. The problem though is it is giving me this linker error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<class BaseClass*,class std::allocator<class BaseClass*> > BaseClass::vector" (?s_Screens@GameScreens@@2V?$vector@PAVGameScreens@@V?$allocator@PAVGameScreens@@@std@@@std@@A)

How do I resolve it?

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil [What is an unresolved external symbol error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2069064)

Comment: @Barry I forgot to initialize my vector in my main. It all works perfectly. Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: @Barry I seem to have 1 more issue. I have a virtual function in my BaseClass that take in values (virtual void Key(int key, int x, int y)). How would I get this to work with my for_each? If I set it up like I did with my other for_each loops it gives me this error: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments .

If I add the arguments then it gives this error:  3 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::mem_fn" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (<error-type>)

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil One question per question! Ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is doable. You need to change your vector to hold `BaseClass*` pointers.

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> vector;

vector.push_back(&a);
vector.push_back(&b);
```

```
void DoSetup(BaseClass *obj)
{
    obj->Setup();
}

for_each (vector.begin(), vector.end(), DoSetup);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `= std::vector();` it's not necessary
2. please move that initialization code `A a; B b; std::....` into the `main` function.
3. Your `for_each` is wrong, too.
4. I don't know what C++ is going to do, if `sizeof(BaseClass)` is zero.

I think you're hiding too much code: what is `GameScreens`?

Comment: `sizeof(BaseClass)` is not zero.

Comment: I don;t know how for_Each works in c++. I just threw it in quickly as an example of what I want it to do. GameScreens is just BaseClass. I missed the call

Comment: you can save `boost::function<void()>` objects than you don't need a base class at all.